# Moving All Files with a Certain Name (Sorting) WINDOWS 8

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, wildcard

Ok, so I have a large amount of ebooks and other files that I would like to sort into folders by Author name. The way I would normally do this in Linux will not work on my Windows 8 laptop. I've been using Powershell, but if there is a better way in Python or by using a bash script I am willing to use whichever can get this done the easiest way. I need it to work recursively because there are many subfolders, (a lot are sorted by genre). What I have tried so far is:

```
mkdir 'C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\BOOKS\Peter Straub'
Copy-Item 'C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\*Peter Straub*' -recurse `
'C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\BOOKS\Peter Straub'
```

Unfortunately for me, that only looks for directories named peter straub. And if i change it to ~\Downloads*Peter Straub*.* it just doesn't work. I tried using the -match and -contains but they failed to work as well. I am relatively new to scripting in windows 8 and would really appreciate anyones help. I would like to implement the read-host -prompt so I don't have to edit the script everytime i run it. And I would like it to actually MOVE the file not just copy but Move-Item doesn't have a recurse option. So could I somehow have the script copy and then delete the original. I tried this also:

```
$author = (read-host -prompt 'Enter Name')
mkdir 'C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\BOOKS\$author'
Copy-Item 'C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\*$author*.*' -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

But this also did not work. I would love to get something like this to work in an automated batch.

So basically I want to pick an authors name, make a new directory using that authors name, then search and move all files containing that authors name into the new directory.

***EDIT*::::
So basically I combined the suggestions of the three answers and what I got works PERFECTLY! Here is the .bat that worked:**

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /p "Author=Enter Name: "
md "%author%"
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('dir C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads /b /s^|find "%author%" /i') do (move "%%i" "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\BOOKS\%author%")
```

**EDIT AGAIN:
So I tried the revised one to try and get it to accept spaces:**

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /p "Author=Please enter an Author: "
md "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\BOOKS\%author%"
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('dir C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads /b /s^|find "%author: =.%" /i') do (move "%%i" "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\BOOKS\%author%")
```

It works correctly in making the directory but it does not **move** the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$author = (read-host -prompt 'Enter Name')

$basedir = 'C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads'
$destdir = "$basedir\BOOKS\$author"
New-Item $destdir -Type directory

Get-ChildItem $basedir -Recurse | ? {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
  $_.Name -like "*$author*" -and
  $_.Directory.FullName -ne $destdir
} | % {
  Copy-Item $_.FullName "$destdir\"
  Remove-Item $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: ERROR:                                           
    Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path     'C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\BOOKS\stephen king \'.
    At line:12 char:3
+   Copy-Item $_.FullName "$destdir\"
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: You have a trailing space in `$author`. Trim the string before assigning it to the variable.

Comment: I see that now. Thank you. But now it just says permission denied, but that is an unrelated issue. I need to find which files are blocked.

Comment: Is there a way to make it move the entire directory if the directory has the name in it and not just the files inside it?

Comment: Remove the `-not` before `$_.PSIsContainer`.

Answer (score 2):

```
set /p author=Please enter an Author: 
md "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\BOOKS\%author%"
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('dir C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads /b /s^|findstr "%author: =*%"') do (move "%%i" "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\BOOKS\%author%"
```

this should work. if not, please comment so I can fix it.

Comment: try this in batch or replace %% with % for command-line. please mark as correct answer if this helped you.

Comment: To add a user prompt, just add this line `set /p "Author=Enter Name: "` and replace "Peter Straub" with `"%Author%"`

Comment: I combined the md %author% with the above and it worked! Thank you guys so much!!!!!!

Comment: How do I deal with spaces, the first one i just used straub because its a unique name, but with Stephen King its not working correctly, i tried "Stephen King" in the prompt and got just a file that said Stephen King as the title i also tried 'Stephen King' and got the same result

Comment: Try that... if not please expound on the issue. `;)`

Comment: It created the directory correctly but didn't move any files.

Comment: try that? I really don't know what the diff between `Peter Straub` and `Stephen King` is. they both have a space.

Comment: It works if I only search "stephen" or "king" but only makes the directory if i type in "Stephen King" i checked a couple files and they are listed as Cujo - Stephen King.epub and another is Misery - Stephen King.lit

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /p "author=Enter the author's name: "
cd /d "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads"
md "books\%author%"
for /r %%a in (*"%author%"*) do move "%%~fa" "books\%author%"
```

Comment: i used the md %author% from this suggestion. Thank you!